# Commit a new State without Flow In Corda

Tags: commit, entity-relationship, corda

I'm trying to control my own `Corda` database, for example, I want to commit a new State without Flow. Can you tell me how to do that? And by a way, Anyone can give me an `Entity Relationship Diagram` of Corda Database.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This would not be straightforward. Here is a broad outline of the steps you would need to perform:

- Use a client utility to create the `SignedTransaction` corresponding to the transaction you want to add to your database (**including the counterparty and notary signatures!**)
- Store the following properties of the transaction for use later on:

  - The transaction's ID
  - The transaction's notary
  - The serialised `SignedTransaction` blob
  - For each output state:

    - Its output index
    - Its contract state class name
  - For each input state:

    - Its state reference (output index and generating transaction ID)
- Log into the node's database by following the instructions [here](https://docs.corda.net/node-database.html)
- Add an entry to the `NODE_TRANSACTIONS` table with the transaction ID and the serialised `SignedTransaction` blob
- For each output state, add an entry to the `VAULT_STATES` table with the information stored earlier

  - The `CONSUMED_TIMESTAMP`, `LOCK_ID` and `LOCK_TIMESTAMP` should be empty
  - The `RECORDED_TIMESTAMP` should be the current time
  - The `STATE_STATUS` should be unconsumed
- For each input state, update its entry in the `VAULT_STATES` table to consumed

  - You can identify the input state in question using its state reference stored earlier

And this is assuming that your state does not implement interfaces that would require updating additional tables, such as `LinearState`, `QueryableState`, `SchedulableState` or `FungibleAsset`.